# Clarity on the key changes of marsh mallow 6.0

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm wanting to clarify on the key changes of marsh mallow 6.0.

Are there any changes that we need to be aware of as developers, as opposed to user only or OS features that do not affect development.

If so how do we manage these changes? example do **we need to disable a feature**,  will it cause **application crashes** or it will open the **setting page and asking for enabling** the feature for that application.

I was so confused about how the recent changes affect developers, I was looking for some clarity.

Comment: This is just a request for the release notes. You can find them as quickly as anybody else.

Comment: I am not asking about release notes.have u used marsh mallow.have u tested u app using marsh mallow.If yes then how u did? can u please tell me.

Comment: @cuihtlauac  you have given api's in  marsh mallow, my question is differs from your comment, just read once my question.

Comment: but that is the new feature(main) of the marsh mallow, I think @cuihtlauac

Comment: yes @MsYvette. can you elaborate my question if you understand clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see there's no need to enable or disable features, the developer needs to be mindful of what target sdk they are developing in when creating or updating apps.

The biggest change to developers in the latest upgrade is Runtime Permissions.

Taken from:
**[Everything every Android Developer must know about new Android's Runtime Permission](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)**

> Although Android is being keep developed but the latest update to Android M is totally different since there is some major change that would change everything like new Runtime Permission. Surprisingly it is not much talked about in Android Developer community even though it is extremely important and may cause some big trouble in the near future.
>
> .../...
>
> You might already feel like there is some cold wind blowing through your arms ... If you are an Android Developer, you will suddenly know that programming logic is totally changed. You cannot just call a function to do the job like previous but you have to check for the permission for every single feature or your application will just simply crash !
>
> Correct. I would not spoil you that it is easy. Although it is a great thing for user but it is truly nightmare for us developer. We have to take coding to the next level or it will surely have a problem in both short-term and long-term.
>
> Anyway this new Runtime Permission will work like described only when we set the application's targetSdkVersion to 23 which mean it is declared that application has already been tested on API Level 23. And this feature will work only on Android 6.0 Marshmallow. The same app will run with same old behavior on pre-Marshmallow device.

This means user permissions are not being requested at install time, but at runtime. This is done using a permission request, and can be saved by the user for one run of the app, or as a default 'always'. This permission can always be revoked in the device settings.

As the api is backward compatible, any devices running with apps of targer sdk < 23 will still be ok.

However these same apps will not run on android devices >= 6.0 with a target sdk of 23 if the runtime permissions are not implemented and the user failing to give permission needs to be managed to stop apps from crashing.

The only manisfest permissions that will require runtime  permission requests are those that are deemed as a dangerous permission level, so accessing personal information, camera, etc.

Permissions are grouped and once a permission is given for one item of a group, permission is then granted for the remaining permissions of the group.

For more detail [Sytem - Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous).

Comment: So I have  one more doubt, you are saying that if the permission is not enabled then some times it may crash, is it right?. So Is there any declaration like camera permission.I don't want to disable for my app, can we declare this permission as final permission.

Comment: I have one quick question from user side, how it will work permission enabling and disabling in >23. That will be handled by Android OS, is it right?

Comment: Ok Thanks.I will look into it.